# How to load server data in realtime on website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the setup. A mobile device sends sensor data to a server. The server hosts a website that will show the data in a chart (i use the Flot framework).

The representation works like this.

```
function showX(){
        $("#dialog").dialog({
        width:400,
        modal:false,
        buttons: {
             "Close": function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }).dialog("open");

    function getRandomData(){
        var randomData = [];
        for(var i = 4;i<100;i++){
            randomData.push([i,(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20))]);
        }
        return randomData;
    }

    var plot = $.plot($("#chart"),[ getRandomData() ]);

    function update() {
        //FETCH SERVER DATA FOR plot.setData();

        plot.setData([ getRandomData() ]);
        plot.draw();

        setTimeout(update, 100);
    }
    update();
}
```

On a button press a dialog that holds a chart appears. The chart is updated with new values in the update function (in the example above with random values). In this function i would like to fetch a chunk of measured data from a server (see comment). What technique should i use? And how should the data be stored on the server side?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use AJAX or Web Sockets.

Comment: What language are you using on the server side?

Comment: I dont know yet. Maybe Java. Maybe C++...

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to advise you on possible implementations without knowing how you are implementing the server. But, assuming you want a cross-browser experience with all the possible fallbacks and your server logic completely separated from the bidirectional client-server communication provided by such solutions like websockets, I would recommend you Pusher: http://pusher.com/

This solution offers you the benefit of using a quasi-polyfill on the client-side that handles browser support and also abstracts the way you communicate stuff to the client using this real-time approach. Check the tutorials.